# How to test a method with parameter in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am not sure how to test #create_arr in the following intersection.rb

intersection.rb

```
class Intersection

  def initialize(xa1, ya1, xa2, ya2, xb1, yb1, xb2, yb2 )
    @xa1 = xa1.to_i
    @ya1 = ya1.to_i
    @xa2 = xa2.to_i
    @ya2 = ya2.to_i
    @xb1 = xb1.to_i
    @yb1 = yb1.to_i
    @xb2 = xb2.to_i
    @yb2 = yb2.to_i

  end
  # compare sizes 
  # both can't have the same size
  def self.check_size?
    rec1 = [(@xa2-@xa1).abs, (@ya2-@ya1).abs]
    rec2 = [(@xb2-@xb1).abs, (@yb2-@yb1).abs]
    rec1 == rec2 or rec1 == rec2.reverse
    # rec1<<rec2.reverse
  end

  def self.create_arr(a, b, c, d)
    (a..c).to_a.product((b..d).to_a)
  end


...
end
```

intersection_spec.rb

```
require './spec_helper'
require './intersection.rb'

describe Intersection do
  before do
    # YES
    @xa1 = 0.0
    @ya1 = 0.0
    @xa2 = 5.0
    @ya2 = 5.0
    @xb1 = 1.0 
    @yb1 = 1.0
    @xb2 = 4.0
    @yb2 = 4.0
    @intersection = Intersection.new(@xa1, @ya1, @xa2, @ya2, @xb1, @yb1, @xb2, @yb2)
  end

  specify{ expect(@intersection.create_arr(@xa1, @ya1, @xa2, @ya2)).to eq [[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [0,4], [0,5], [1,0], [1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [1,5], [2,0], [2,1], [2,2], [2,3], [2,4], [2,5], [3,0], [3,1], [3,2], [3,3], [3,4], [3,5], [4,0], [4,1], [4,2], [4,3], [4,4], [4,5], [5,0], [5,1], [5,2], [5,3], [5,4], [5,5]] }

end
```

This gives `TypeError: can't iterate from Float`.

One way I can do is change `@xa1 = (1.0).to_i` but then what I do in the initialize becomes useless.

What is the best way to test `#create_arr` which take parameters?

Comment: Do you (and if so why?) *have* to re-use same instance variables for `.create_arr` and `.new` in the test code? If you can answer that, then that will lead to correct fix (either in the test or in your Intersection class).

Answer (score 0):

One issue you will run into is that your create_arr method is a class method on Intersection. The problem you're running into may be related to calling a class method on an instance of your class.

I would suggest briefly reading up on the differences between Class & Instance methods to understand what's going on there. [RailsTips](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) has a good explination of the differences.

To use the create_arr method as stands below you would call Intersection.create_arr(...) and not @intersection.create_arr(...).

```
class Intersection
...
  def self.create_arr(a, b, c, d)
    (a..c).to_a.product((b..d).to_a)
  end    
...
end
```

To change the method to be an instance method, you remove the 'self.' from the method declaration within the class. This way you would call create_arr on an instance of the Intersection class by doing @intersection.create_arr(...).

```
class Intersection
...
  def create_arr(a, b, c, d)
    (a..c).to_a.product((b..d).to_a)
  end    
...
end
```

Lastly, to address the other question on testing your class. I would suggest using 'it' blocks and '.should' to clarify your RSpec up. I've included an example refactor of your code below.

```
class Intersection
...
  #=> refactored to use arrays and ranges for 4 arguments, you could make this take range values as params to make this less tied to arrays of 4 objects.
  def self.create_arr(args = [])
    args[0..2].product(args[1..3])
  end    
...
end

require './spec_helper'
require './intersection.rb'

describe Intersection do
  before do
    @xa1 = 0.0
    @ya1 = 0.0
    @xa2 = 5.0
    @ya2 = 5.0
    @xb1 = 1.0 
    @yb1 = 1.0
    @xb2 = 4.0
    @yb2 = 4.0
    @intersection = Intersection.new(@xa1, @ya1, @xa2, @ya2, @xb1, @yb1, @xb2, @yb2)
  end

  it 'creates an array of tuples' do
    @expected_results = [[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [0,4], [0,5], [1,0], [1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [1,5], [2,0], [2,1], [2,2], [2,3], [2,4], [2,5], [3,0], [3,1], [3,2], [3,3], [3,4], [3,5], [4,0], [4,1], [4,2], [4,3], [4,4], [4,5], [5,0], [5,1], [5,2], [5,3], [5,4], [5,5]]
    @results = Intersection.create_arr([@xa1, @ya1, @xa2, @ya2])
    @results.should eq(@expected_results)
  end
end
```